# Basemap seems to be missing plot visuals like blue marble and certain projections

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Basemap is missing blue marble and several other projections. How do I add them? Or is there an issue with my installation?

Tried out the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution=None, lat_0=50, lon_0=-100)
m.bluemarble(scale=0.5);
plt.show()
```

This code just produces a black circle with a white background when I was expecting a blue marble sphere.
[image]

Comment: Are there any warning or error messages?

Comment: No error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine on my computer. And the output is as follows:

[image]

I suspect that one or more packages (i.e. pillow) are missing in your environment.

Comment: Apparently I have pillow `pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied` But when I do `help("modules")` I dont see pillow or PIL

Comment: I uploaded what I am getting above

Comment: Try `import pillow` in the environment that you run `Basemap` to confirm that it is installed in the place you need.