# Unable to use `Basemap` and `bluemarble`

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

The problem is exactly the same as the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436969/basemap-seems-to-be-missing-plot-visuals-like-blue-marble-and-certain-projection) and using the same code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution=None, lat_0=50, lon_0=-100)
m.bluemarble(scale=0.5)
plt.show()
```

This results in the same empty circle. I do get a warning:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

which results from the input data to `imshow()` being all zero. If I run the code without the projection

```py
m = Basemap(resolution=None, lat_0=50, lon_0=-100)
```

I get (rather badly drawn) map of the world, which suggests to me that all the libraries are installed.

I think the data gets zeroed out with the code here from `mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py`  but as I don't understand what it's doing it doesn't help me much:

```py
self._bm_rgba_warped = \
ma.masked_array(self._bm_rgba_warped,mask=mask)
# make points outside projection limb transparent.
self._bm_rgba_warped = self._bm_rgba_warped.filled(0.)
```

Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in google colab and did this:

```
!pip uninstall matplotlib
!pip install matplotlib==3.4.3
```

Then it worked.  Found solution in comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72828168/started-using-mpl-toolkits-basemap-while-execution-of-code-jupyter-notebook-not) which had a link to [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/463#issuecomment-1217968107).  Basically there's a bug in 3.5 and higher versions of matplot lib that causes the clipping.